# How do I create an event using the SocialTables API?

Tags: social-tables

I'm trying to use the `/4.0/legacyvm3/teams/{team}/events` endpoint to create an event. I'm running into some trouble with `spaces`.

I used the `/4.0/legacyvm3/teams/{team}/venues` endpoint to get a list of venues. I chose one to include in the `spaces` section and posted this:

```
{
  "name": "Event via API Test 04",
  "category": "athletic event",
  "public": true,
  "attendee_management": true,
  "start_time": "2017-04-05T16:13:54.217Z",
  "end_time": "2017-04-05T16:13:54.217Z",
  "uses_metric": false,
  "venue_mapper_version": 0,
  "spaces": [
    {
      "venue_id": 128379,
      "name": "Snurrrggggg"
    }
  ]
}
```

The endpoint returns a `400` code and this error:

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"
}
```

I tried including the `wizard` section, but each time it would return this error:

```
{
  "message": "Access Denied to this feature"
}
```

After some experimentation, this body succeeded:

```
{
  "name": "Event via API Test 03",
  "category": "athletic event",
  "public": true,
  "attendee_management": true,
  "start_time": "2017-04-05T16:13:54.217Z",
  "end_time": "2017-04-05T16:13:54.217Z",
  "uses_metric": false,
  "venue_mapper_version": 0,
  "spaces": [
    {
      "name": "Fake News Room"
    }
  ]
}
```

But the application itself would not display the diagram, and the newly created room did not show up in my list of venues. Perhaps it did not assign permissions to it?

In any case, I don't actually want to create a new venue/space. I want to pass in an existing venue/space. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is to create a working diagram in 4.0 you will need to POST some data to the /4.0/diagrams endpoint.

The room you create doesn't map to the same concept as venues.  When you create an event as you did, it creates a new space entity. The spaces endpoints can return information on those.

Comment: So how do I create an event with an existing space? I cannot figure out how to query them.

Comment: ... or are you saying I need to create a space for each event and then create a blank diagram?

Comment: The linkage goes Event can have a space and a diagram.  Event can have many spaces and many diagrams.  Diagram is linked to one and only one space and one and only one event.

Comment: We're looking to get rid of spaces in the 4.0 api entirely but for now that's the way it currently works.

Comment: Spaces should covered by the following endpoints:https://developer.socialtables.com/api-console#/Spaces